# Why BigDecimal constructor instance with differents values?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I don't know why this happens:

```
float flo = 196.7f;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(flo);
System.out.println(bd); //print 196.6999969482421875

BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(flo));
System.out.println(bd2); //print 196.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your questions are clearly stated in the Javadoc.

> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>      BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>      a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>      0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>      matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>      that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>      0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> 2. The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which
>      is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is
>      generally recommended that the String constructor be used in
>      preference to this one.